# What code should I use for my GLMM, glmer, lmer?

Tags: r, glm, lme4, glmulti

I Want to use the dependent variable "Herps" (count data) to understand what response variables are important influencing herpetofauna species richness. The response variables include Total_Saplings, Total_Understorey_Vegetation, Mean_Leaf_Litter_Depth, Mean_Canopy_Openess, Tree_Species_Richness, Mean_DBH, Large_Trees, Total_Basal_Area, Aguada_Distance_Category, and I want to include "Year" as a random variable.

I've not used R before, and this is a steep learning curve for myself. I appreciate any help offered. Thanks

Hi. So I've tried using a couple of codes myself but I don't seem to be getting anywhere, some of these codes include:

1)

```
AllHerpsRichness <- glmulti(Rich_All_Herps ~ Total_Saplings * Total_Understorey_Vegetation * Tree_Species_Richness + 
                                             Mean_DBH * Total_Basal_Area * Mean_Canopy_Openess * 
                                             Mean_Leaf_Litter_Depth * Aguada_Distance_Category * 
                                             Camp * (1|Year), data=Habitat,
                                             level=1, fitfunction=glm, crit="aicc",
                                             confsetsize=256, family="poisson")
```

but I get the error

> Error in Total_Saplings + Total_Understorey_Vegetation +   Tree_Species_Richness +  :
> non-numeric argument to binary operator

2. 

```
AllHerpsRichness <- lmer(Rich_All_Herps ~ Total_Saplings * Total_Understorey_Vegetation * 
                                          Tree_Species_Richness * Mean_DBH + 
                                          Total_Basal_Area * Mean_Canopy_Openess * 
                                          Mean_Leaf_Litter_Depth * Aguada_Distance_Category * Camp *
                                          (1|Year),
                 data=Habitat)
```

but I receive the error

> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

3. 

```
AllHerpsRichness <- lmer(Rich_All_Herps ~ Total_Saplings * Total_Understorey_Vegetation * 
                                          Tree_Species_Richness * Mean_DBH + 
                                          Total_Basal_Area * Mean_Canopy_Openess * 
                                          Mean_Leaf_Litter_Depth * Aguada_Distance_Category * 
                                          Camp * (1|Year),
                 data=Habitat)
```

but the error

> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
> Warning message:
> In glmer(Rich_All_Herps ~ Total_Saplings *   Total_Understorey_Vegetation *  :
> calling glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link) as a shortcut   to lmer() is deprecated; please call lmer() directly

I'm not sure if either one of these codes I've already tried is right, but does anyone know how I can fix one of them to try and get some outputs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is your question? Are you looking for the code to do all that? That's not really the purpose of this site. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make sure you get the help you need.

Comment: Hi Harrison, sorry for that. I've updated the post, hopefully it's clearer now

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think `glmulti` handles random effects, and 'multiplying' (*) by `(1|Year)` would break things anyway.
2. A singular fit is not necessarily a problem, it typically means you might want to simplify your model. Read e.g. the help file at `?lme4::isSingular`, or the [relevant section in the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1).
3. Your error message doesn't match your code here, I suspect a transcription error (it's generally best to *directly* cut-and-paste your code so that what you post matches the code you actually ran directly): you must have specified `family = gaussian` ?

We would need more details to give you more advice, and the question might be better suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), but I would suggest:

```r
glmer(Rich_All_Herps ~ Total_Saplings + Total_Understorey_Vegetation + 
       <... more covariates ... > + Camp + (1|Year),
                 data=Habitat,
                 family = poisson)
```

as a start, because:

- a Poisson model is a good starting guess for count data (you definitely need to check for overdispersion after fitting the initial model and consider switching to a negative binomial or observation-level random effect (Harrison 2015), see `lme4::glmer.nb` or switch to `glmmTMB`)
- random effects (e.g. `(1|Year)` are always added, not multiplied by, other covariates in the formula
- additive effects (+ rather than *) make more sense to start with, unless:

  - you have a very large data set (all-way interactions among `n` covariates requires `2^n` parameters)
  - you're optimistic about your ability to interpret many-way interactions
  - you have *particular* interactions that are of interest, or perhaps model all 2-way interactions (if mildly optimistic; still requires `choose(n, 2) + n + 1` parameters)

---

Harrison, Xavier A. 2014. “Using Observation-Level Random Effects to Model Overdispersion in Count Data in Ecology and Evolution.” PeerJ 2 (October): e616. https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.616.

Comment: Thank you for your help Ben, this has been really helpful.